# Which LayoutManager should I use for my Java GUI?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I want to make a GUI and do it through code rather than dragging everything around like in Netbeans. I would like to, if possible, set the coordinates for each thing I am to insert as it will provide me with the precision I desire. I have tried out GridBagLayout and have not found it to be to my liking but perhaps I don't know enough about it to know what to do. Perhaps MigLayout is a good option for me but I'd like to know if there's anything better for what I need.

In Summary: I want to make a GUI where I can directly specific coordinates of each object added. Which Layout do I use?

Comment: What you want to do is to avoid any layout manager. The point of a layout manager is to make the components laid out correctly regardless of the look & feel, fonts, etc. Using absolute coordinates defeats the purpose of a layout manager. Learn how to use them: that's the good thing to do.

Comment: @JB Nizet I'm obviously new to swing. Either way, is there a simple way to add a component along with the coordinates you want it at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do both. Try [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) in Eclipse. It provides two-way design and code generation.

Comment: It would be helpful but I need to be dynamically creating objects in my GUI. That's why I want to stick to just coding.

Comment: You can still do that. WindowBuilder just takes the gruntwork out of generating GUIs. Lay it out visually, manually tweak the code, and load it back into WindowBuilder if you want. I generally don't do the third step, but the option is there, especially for a quick sanity check.

Comment: I installed this. Very helpful. I ended up using this alongside with another suggestion, in the end.

Answer (score 5):

For each panel you can/should have different layout managers, according to the layout you are going to have inside. There is no "universal" layout manager, and especially when handcoding, it's elegant and useful to use the "most appropriate" layout manager for the task you are solving. For example, the otherwise very advanced GridBagLayout cannot emulate WrapLayout.

You may find [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) useful as a list of hints for proper layout manager selection.

Note however that each layout manager has its quirks in Swing, so switching from one layout manager to another will possibly bring you some small troubles. For example, some of them respect Minimum/MaximumSize, some don't, etc.

To your summary: you shouldn't try to set the coordinates "manually". While this is possible, it's much better to express the relation between the visual elements in a logical way. This will help you a lot for making your page resizable, for addressing localization, for proper nesting and extracting controls, and at many other places which I don't remember at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [CoordinateLayout](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/layouts/CoordinateLayout.html) :

> Allows laying out components based on absolute positions/sizes that
>   are adapted based on available space for the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Specyfing coordinatates (i.e. using the `NullLayout`) is always a bad idea. The `LayoutManager` classes should always be used to handle your component placement, as it will handle all types of events you should not be handling (such as computing new coordinates when the container is resized).

I personally prefer to use a `GridBagLayout`, as it allows you to specify all types of constraints (how to distribute free space, how much space a component will use, the insets, etc.). [This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) will help you get started on the `GridBagLayout`.

Other `LayoutManager` exist, each having strength and weaknesses (e.g. `Flow Layout`, `MigLayout`, `BoxLayout`). Depending on your needs, some managers might be too simple, or overkill. You should try and learn many of them so you can find the proper one for your needs.

Comment: My GUI is to be used for a demonstration to my class so it's basically going to be animating. I need to be dynamically creating/removing objects from the screen. I'll try out GridBagLayout some more though.

Comment: @chickeneaterguy It is possible with all `LayoutManager` classes to dynamically create/remove objects from the containers. Your "needs" should be interpreted as how complex is your GUI layout, how many objects you have to display, the level of control over component placement through constraints you want.